# Why is an enum variable an rvalue here?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, rvalue, lvalue

Example:

```cpp
typedef enum Color
{
    RED,
    GREEN,
    BLUE
} Color;

void func(unsigned int& num)
{
    num++;
}

int main()
{
    Color clr = RED;
    func(clr);
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error when I compile this:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':

<source>:16:9: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'unsigned int&' to an rvalue of type 'unsigned int'

     func(clr);

         ^~~
```

I think the variable (`clr`) I pass to `func(unsigned int&)` is an lvalue. I can get the address of `clr` and can assign another value to it. Why does it turn into an rvalue when I try to pass it to `func(unsigned int&)`?

Comment: Ask yourself: Is an `enum` a `unsigned int`?

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica In my original opinion, I think `typedef enum` is not a native type, and C++ would treat it as an `unsigned int` type indeed.

Comment: GCC's error message is suboptimal in this case. Clang will give a less confusing message by printing the original type of `clr`.

Comment: @cpplearner yep, that's why I thought `enum type` is treat as `unsigned int` in C++.

Comment: `enum X` is its own type, distinct from `int`

Comment: The compiler can choose to make the type for instance `unsigned char`. Then there is indeed a mismatch in type. Since the compiler must be free to choose the type, an error is generated.

Comment: What happens if you type `typedef enum Color : unsigned int`?

Comment: @JL2210 Sorry, I dont get it. What's this type for?

Comment: Typed enums. It allows you to specify the type of an enum's members

Comment: @JL2210 O I see. I try it and get the same result. Seems it still would implicitly convert to rvalue if I keep passing a not `unsigned int` type lvalue to `unsigned int&`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`clr` itself is an lvalue of type `Color`. But the function does not accept a `Color`. It accepts a (reference to) `unsigned int`. So, the argument is converted (implicitly). And the result of the conversion is a prvalue of type `unsigned int`.

Comment: Yep, I try `func(Color&)` before I ask the question, and it compile pass. I just thought C++ would treat `enum` type as `unsigned int` type in compiling. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: One thing that adds to the confusion is that C is almost a perfect subset of C++. At least, anything you can do in C, you can do in C++ with almost identical code, especially on gcc/clang. You will also need compiler dependent constructs as the C++ replacement for 'restrict' in C that is provided by gcc. Enums are different in C and C++, for example, if someColor is enum, 'someColor = 1' is legal C, but not C++.

Answer (score 0):

enum type init and assignment must be enum inside，so enum type can't is lvalue。
void func(unsigned int& num) this function need quote type

Comment: If I change `func(unsigned int&)` to `func(Color&)`, compiler accept it. So I think enum type variable is a lvalue.

Comment: no, because enum type can't assignment int enum define outside

Comment: You mean it still a rvalue? But I bind a not-const lvalue reference to it in `func(Color&)`, and it pass.

Comment: yes， it still a rvalue，func(Color& key) this function param key only assignment RED,GREEN,BLUE , Otherwise it will error。

Comment: you can see [this cpp instructions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum)

Comment: thanks for link shared. I know a enum type variable can only accept the value within its enum defined scope. But is it the reason that make enum type variable be a `rvalue`?

Comment: @Koen the problem is not with the enum. You'd get a similar error if you called e.g. `func(5u);`

Comment: Thanks @Ruslan. I think the comments under this answer is outside the original question. I just could't agree with the opinion of `enum type variable is rvalue` in the answer.